# How to get warnings of incorrect string formatting (C++)

Tags: gcc, warnings, printf, compiler-warnings

apologies in advance if i use poor terminology.

when i compile a C++ app under gdb and use printf() it gives me awesome warnings relating to the consistency of the format string and the arguments passed in.

eg, this code:

```
printf("%s %s", "foo");
```

results in a compiler warning "too few arguments for format", which is super-useful.
it will also give warnings about format string type vs. argument type.
it must have inspected the format string and compared that against the supplied argument types.
- is this sort of compile-time introspection something which can be added to ordinary source code, or is it something which needs to be compiled into gcc itself ?

fwiw this is under gcc 4.2.1 on os x.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do stuff like this for your own printf-like functions (as well as for scanf/strftime/strfmon-like functions):

```
#define PRINTF_FORMAT_CHECK(format_index, args_index) __attribute__ ((__format__(printf, format_index, args_index)))

void my_printf(const char *fmt, ...) PRINTF_FORMAT_CHECK(1, 2);
```

See the [gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) for further details.

Comment: There are a bunch of other options in the manual; they can't be enough to cover the general case of all variadic functions though.

Comment: huh; nifty. thanks Paul.
from the man page:
"The format attribute specifies that a function takes printf, scanf, strftime or strfmon style arguments which should be type-checked against a format string"

so it looks like if i have my own nutty constraints (eg something other than the printf- family of functions) this wouldn't really do the trick, but there's a whole bunch of other interesting __attributes__ in the page you linked to. thanks !

Comment: Awesome. Anyone know if the Intel C compiler has something similar? I couldn't find anything in the manual.

Comment: @pavon: I *think* ICC may support this also, but I can't easily check right now - give it a try - it either supports it or just silently ignores it, but I'm not sure which.